# Vertical align and background color issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is probably an easy fix for you guys. In Bootstrap 4, I am using `align-self-center` and `mx-auto` to vertical center the `h4` and the content in these grids and it's working fine, but the alignment is also changing the height of the grid and that stops the background color to be fully applied to the grid. This will be generated by the CMS and I need to keep the white padding around the yellow. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container widget4-wrapper h-100">
    <div class="row widget4 align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-sm-4 your-checklist mx-auto">
        <h3>Checklist header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 checklist mx-auto">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue. Sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non. Consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue. Sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet. Quis risus sed vulputate odio ut.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
body { background-color: #182B54 }
.widget4 {
    padding: 25px 25px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.widget4 .your-checklist,
.widget4 .checklist { background-color: #FED007 }
```

And **[this is how it looks](https://codepen.io/wpdevops/pen/LYZbvLa)** now

What I want is to make it look like this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simple css change will exactly copy the screenshot you provided:

```
.widget4 {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: #FED007;
    border: 20px white solid;
    border-bottom: none; 
 }
```

Comment: changed it to padding: 0 and now this is perfect with less code, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need this css:

```css
.widget4 {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FED007;
}
.widget4-wrapper {
  padding: 25px 25px 0 25px; /* change these values as you like */
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

for it to look like your screenshot.

Comment: this worked for me but i opted for the other answer since it's less code.. thank you though :)

Answer (score 1):

Modified html and css is below. Modified lines are signed by comment ------Changed!------
Good luck!

```
<div class="container widget4-wrapper h-100">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">   <!-- --------------------changed!---------------- -->
        <div class="row widget4 align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-sm-4 your-checklist mx-auto">
                <h3>Checklist header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 checklist mx-auto">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Volutpat consequat 
                mauris nunc congue nisi. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc 
                congue. Sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. 
                Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien. 
                Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non. Consequat semper 
                viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Mattis enim ut tellus elementum 
                sagittis vitae. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet. Viverra 
                aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit. 
                Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Nulla 
                facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi 
                tincidunt augue. Sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet. Quis 
                risus sed vulputate odio ut.</p>
            </div>
        </div>     <!-- --------------changed---------------- -->
    </div>
</div>
```

```
body { background-color: #182B54 }
.inner-wrapper {   /* -------------changed!------------ */
  padding: 25px 25px 0;   /* -------------changed!------------ */
  background-color: #fff;   /* -------------changed!------------ */
}   /* -------------changed!------------ */
.widget4 {
    background-color: #FED007;   /* -------------changed!------------ */
}
.widget4 .your-checklist,
.widget4 .checklist { background-color: #FED007 }
```